# How do you slice an image in corona sdk?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How do you slice up an image like in the photo provided?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corona alone does not provide anything to achieve this.

But you can use other libraries or plugins to process the image which you then display in Corona as external bitmap textures.

Please refer to https://coronalabs.com/blog/2016/09/22/introducing-external-bitmap-textures/